# Why doesn't the moveTaskToBack() method work on the signed APK?

Tags: android

I want to move my app to the background after the user presses  the `BACK` button.

I am using:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  MessageListActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

It works properly in debug mode.
But it's not working in the signed APK. The app closed completely after the `BACK` button is pressed.

Comment: make your activity launch mode `launchMode=singleTop`

Comment: Thank .It's singleTop right now. But it does not work.